# Ubuntu installation always restarts

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded `ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` and mounted it to USB. I restart my laptop, select Install Linux and select language, then it says I have no internet, I press "Continue", and then I click "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8" and click "Continue", the computer just restarts and I see the again the same Try-Ubuntu-or-install-it menu.

And hence I cannot install Ubuntu. I check md5 hash for iso and it's correct.

Thanks for any help. P.S. I couldn't find answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Create ubuntu bootable disk through [`unetbootin`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/) software.

Comment: Done this, but same thing, after I press Continue it restarts into same screen with choice of installing/trying ubuntu. Am I supposed to remove USB after clicking continue?

Comment: Try to burn the `.iso` file to dvd.Booting from that dvd will solve your issue.